# new array from existing array using specific elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I am still learning, I have tried to find a solution for this but I think I am missing/overlooked something and can't seem to crack it,

I am creating a node .js file and inside,

I have this function,

```
var goingTomorrow = rows.filter(ifDateTomorrow);
        function ifDateTomorrow(value) {
            return value[5] === dateTomorrow;
        }
```

Which returns all rows where element 5 in the array === tomorrows date to the variable goingTomorrow, this works.

Then I have,

```
var sum = 0;
        for (var x = 0; x < goingTomorrow.length; x++) {
            sum += + goingTomorrow[x][6];
            }

console.log(goingTomorrow.length + ' Bookings: ' + sum + ' pax total for tomorrow');
```

Which calculates the total people for the day by adding all elements in the 5th index to return a total. Also works.

But now I would like to return a new array with only specific elements/indexes to be sent in an email (so all the fields aren't needed).

I use, `goingTomorrow` to run the code. `goingTomorrow` currently outputs:

```
1,John,w,tourname,2018-08-14,2018-08-14,3,820467370,test address,AS,0,john@xxx.com,0,6,James,M,tourname,2018-08-05,2018-08-14,2,54546456,test address,AS,0,james@xxx.com,0,
```

But in the email but I would like to choose the specific elements to output as well as output into a array with each result on a new line.

This is what I want to have output,

```
John,w,2018-08-14,3,820467370,test address,john@xxx.com, 
James,M,2018-08-14,2,54546456,test address,james@xxx.com,
```

I have tried foreach, map, reduce and newArray to little success.

So, how do I create a new array from goingTomorrow with the specific elements I want. What am I missing? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) for the wanted indices and map a new array.

```js
var array = [[1, 'John', 'w', 'tourname', '2018-08-14', '2018-08-14', 3, '820467370', 'test address', 'AS', 0, 'john@xxx.com', 0], [6, 'James', 'M', 'tourname', '2018-08-05', '2018-08-14', 2, '54546456', 'test address', 'AS', 0, 'james@xxx.com', 0]],
    result = array.map(({ 1: name, 2: gender, 4: date, 7: number, 11: email }) =>
        [name, gender, date, number, email]);

console.log(result);
document.body.innerHTML += result.join('<br>');
```

Comment: Thanks Nina, so I do,

`var newArray = [goingTomorrow],
                result = newArray.map(({ 1: name, 2: lname, 5: tourdate, 7: phone, 11: email }) =>
[name, lname, tourdate, phone, email]);
console.log(result)` 

But get all fields mapped as well us undefined after the first. 
    `[ [ [ '6',
      'James',
      'M',
      'DWTCT',
      '2018-08-05',
      '2018-08-15',
      '2',
      '54546456',
      'test address',
      'AS',
      '0',
      'james@sensison.com',
      '0' ],
    undefined,
    undefined,
    undefined,
    undefined ] ]`

Comment: Ok I got it to output the specific elements, I needed to use `newArrar = goingTomorrow` not `newArray = [tomorrow]`

Now just to output them to new lines as they are still output in one line.

Comment: Thank you for the help @Nina, Understanding how map works a bit better now. I now get my array output as desired but its still on one line, how can I put each array in the newly created array on its own line?

Comment: Thanks Nina, the arrays selected elements are now output using the map function you suggested. When running, the terminal logs each array on its own new line like, 

`[ [ 'Josh', 'w', '2018-08-15', '820467370', 'josh@xxx.com' ],
  [ 'James', 'M', '2018-08-15', '54546456', 'james@xxx.com' ] ]`

but in the html it returns with 

`Josh,w,2018-08-15,820467370,josh@xxx.com,James,M,2018-08-15,54546456,james@xxx.com,`

I would like to output it as 

`Josh,w,2018-08-15,820467370,josh@xxx.com, <br>
James,M,2018-08-15,54546456,james@xxx.com,`

Tried adding '<br>' but it breaks the array.

Comment: you could join the arrays with `'<br>'`.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you!
I used, `result = result.join(',<br>'); console.log(result);` and it works!

Answer (score 0):

Look like you want to use the map function for this.
The map function lets you return a modify element for each element from the original array.

Example:

```
newArray = originalArray.map((currentElementFromTheArray, indexOfThisElementInTheArray, originalArray) => { return newElement; })
```

Comment: Thanks for the input too, I managed using the working example above with some slight edits for my data. Was trying to wrap my head around it but the example made it clearer, I was struggling with making documentation reality.